# Matlab Simulink how to omit signal in some steps

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to segment the original signal using the DSP toolbox in Matlab Simulink. I'm using the Time scope to plot it. If the original signal has certain characteristics, I plot it.  If not, I omit the signal segment.  However, when I omit signals, the time scope stops the simulaiton entirely.
What I want to plot is:
original signal: |seg good1|seg bad1|seg bad2|seg good2|...
filtered signal: |seg good1|seg good2|seg good3|...
How to plot the filtered signal?

Comment: Please, can you describe how your original signal looks like, upload an image of your model and explain how are you currently omitting the unwanted signals?

Comment: I do not think it is possible with the time scopes. You would need to create your own plotting routine. These blocks use time as x-axis and would skip the gaps when plotting.